# JSF SelectOneRadio button can't be disabled

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, web-applications

I've two radio button which are backed by two instance variables of a Backed bean in JSF{That is the requirement, not to bind with one variable.}. And, If one is checked, other one should be disabled. Below is my code, What is the wrong with it? Why it doesn't work as I expected.

appropriate help appreciated.

```
    <h:graphicImage url="/images/orange_arrows.gif" />
       <h:outputLabel for="addBundle">
          <h:outputText value="Subscribe Bundle :" styleClass="item-name"/>
       </h:outputLabel>


    <h:selectOneRadio id="addBundle" value="#{accountAdjustmentBean.bundleAdded}" required="false"
                    onchange="enableSubmit( this.checked != bundleAdded );disableRadioButton('unsubscribe');">
                    <f:selectItem id="subscribe" itemValue="true"/>
       <h:message styleClass="errors" for="addBundle"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGroup/>

    <h:graphicImage url="/images/orange_arrows.gif" />
       <h:outputLabel for="removeBundle">
          <h:outputText value="Unsubscribe Bundle" styleClass="item-name"/>
       </h:outputLabel>


    <h:selectOneRadio id="removeBundle" value="#{accountAdjustmentBean.bundleRemoved}" required="false"
                onchange="enableSubmit( this.checked != bundleRemoved );disableRadioButton('subscribe');">
            <f:selectItem id="unsubscribe" itemValue="true"/>
       <h:message styleClass="errors" for="removeBundle"/>
     </h:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="adjustments-submit">
        <h:commandButton id="submitBtn" action="#{accountAdjustmentBean.addDataBundleAction}"
                     value="Submit"/>


<f:verbatim>
    <script  type="text/javascript">

        function enableSubmit( enable ) {
            document.getElementById('ccAcountStatus:submitBtn').disabled = !enable;
        }

        // Disable submit button on load (enable when account locked status changes)
        enableSubmit(false);

        function disableRadioButton(elementId)    {
            document.getElementById(elementId).disabled = true;
    }

        // save the account locked status at page load. used to detect if changed.
        var bundleadded = </f:verbatim><h:outputText value="#{accountAdjustmentBean.bundleAdded}"/><f:verbatim>

    </script>
</f:verbatim>
```

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons are not connected to each other.

What you could do is bind only one and use script to unselect the other. In your bean do the same, when Boolean a is set to true, set b to false and the other way around.

Comment: I can enable/disable the submit button when there is a changes in the radio button, so, in the same way can't I enable/disable these tow radio buttons?